# Error received while connecting to Laravel app on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I get the following error after having deployed my Laravel app to AWS ElasticBeanstalk for the first time. The health check is green. I've changed the environment and database settings to match those on AWS, as instructed by AWS docs.

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109:
file_put_contents(/var/app/current/myapp-master/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This is at the line 109:

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `/bootstrap/cache` directory and set correct permission on it:

```
chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Now it says: ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:

At line 412 in there: 
    function includeFile($file)
    {
        include $file;
    }

Comment: Try to delete everything in `cache` directory and run `composer dumpauto` command